# How to develop a chart in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a set of data in an excel sheet, I need to create a chart with these values. please suggest me or provide me samples how to proceed further. I tried to scatter chart it's not showing properly. Thanks in Advance

```
  Date    Time    Max bills published
   1/1    22:00      5
   1/2    03:00      10
   1/3    08:00      47
   1/4    10:00      56
   1/5    13:00      47
   1/6    10:00      42
   1/7    23:00      2
   1/8    20:00      10
   1/9    14:00      36
  1/10    15:00      48
  1/11    09:00      59
  1/12    09:00      65
  1/13    14:00      45
  1/14    19:00      1
  1/15    22:00      5
```

Time: time @ which the max bills published by the user.

For example,

On Jan 1st between 12:00-13:00 there were 3 bills published by the user.

On Jan 1st between 22:00-23:00 there were 5 bills published by the user.

we are taking only the max bills published in one hour. so we are considering only the second record.. likewise I took for the whole month

got the data from SQL server.

Comment: You haven't specified what kind of chart you need. You should provide a mockup of what it should look like.

Comment: @DavidPostill : any kind of chart is fine with me

Answer (score 0):

If you select all 3 columns, then in click `Insert` tab and select the `Bar Chart` drop down then click any chart then you should get a nice bar chart showing that data you selected.

[image: Excel Chart Example]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column for Date and Time, select it with the Max column and click on line chart

[image]

Selecting the three column Date, Time and Max you can Insert the following Chart

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick response. is it possible to have only date on the X-Axis  and time on the secondary axis something like that..

Comment: You can use the Date only and put the Time in Data Table

Comment: thanx again. Can u provide d snap for me plz.. how to show time value in Data table

Comment: You can select all three column Date, Time and Max and Insert Chart, choose the one you want it will automatically show Date and Time on X-Axis